# Allocating unknown char[] in dynamically reading a file in c

Tags: c

```
char* freadline(FILE* fp){ 
   
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int lSize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char *buffer = malloc(lSize);
    fread(buffer, 1, lSize, fp);
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(lSize), fp);
    
    return buffer;
}
```

but it doesn't read line by line any suggestions as to how this would be read line by line

Comment: [realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) can be used to increase the buffer size as needed. But it is not clear what you are trying to do exactly. Code like this makes no sense: `line = malloc(sizeof(buffer)*NCHAR); line = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);` The second statement throws away the allocated memory from the first statement. Results in a memory leak and also means that `line` points to a local variable which is invalid once the function exits.

Comment: The sensible approach in the generic case is to name an allowed max length, read the string into a local array of that max length with fgets, then malloc afterwards, when you know the length.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple solutions here.
The first is to get the size of the entire file using [fseek](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) and [ftell](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/) fseek will allow you to go to the end of file and ftell will give you the current position which can be used as a size indicator. You can then allocate enough of a buffer to read the entire file then split them up into lines.

The other solution is to use a temporary buffer of 1000 or so like you're already doing, read a character at a time using [fgetc](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/) in a loop and feed it into the temporary buffer until you hit a new line indicator , then use the strlen method to get the length and allocate a buffer of that size, copy the temporary buffer then return the allocated buffer.

There is also errors in your code as pointed out in the comments. You're discarding your allocated memory resulting in a leak. And your freadline doesn't actually read a line it just reads whatever size you're telling it to read.

Comment: I tried this:
```
char* freadline(FILE* fp){ 
   
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int lSize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char *buffer = malloc(lSize);
    fread(buffer, 1, lSize, fp);


    return buffer;
}

But it doesn't read line by line, it reads the whole file

Comment: Option 3: Use existing `getline` instead of re-implementing it.  This is POSIX rather than C, though.

Answer (score 0):

> the lines in the file could be of any length.

`realloc()` is a classic approach, but how about a simple, slow and plodding one:
Read once to find line length, seek, allocate, then read again to save the line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char* freadline(FILE *fp) {
  int length = 0;
  long offset = ftell(fp);
  if (offset == -1)
    return NULL;
  int scan_count = fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]%n", &length); // Save scan length
  if (scan_count == EOF)
    return NULL;
  if (fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET))
    return NULL;
  size_t n = length + 1u;  // +1 for potential \n
  char *buf = malloc(n + 1); // + 1 for \0
  if (buf == NULL)
    return NULL;
  size_t len = fread(buf, 1, n, fp);
  buf[len] = '\0';
  return buf;
}
```

Test

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  FILE *fp = fopen("tmp.txt", "w+");
  assert(fp);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int l = i * 7;
    for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
      fputc(rand() % 26 + 'a', fp);
    }
    fputc('\n', fp);
  }
  rewind(fp);
  char *s;
  while ((s = freadline(fp)) != NULL) {
    printf("<%s>", s);
    free(s);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
<
><lvqdyoq
><ykfdbxnqdquhyd
><jaeebzqmtblcabwgmscrn
><oiaftlfpcuqffaxozqegxmwgglkh
><vxtdhnzqankyprbwteazdafeqxtijjtkwea
><zqgmplohyxrutojvbzllqgjaidbtqibygdzcxkujvw
><ghwbmjjmbpksnzkgzgiluiggpkzwhaetclrcyxcsixsutjmrm
><vqlybsjnihnfqyfhyszwgpsvnhnngdnjzjypqcflnztrhcfgbkakzxam
><alsuauxxchqjxqaiddtjszgcbullyyjymytioyawpzshhfpqpsatddbcagjgobm
>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok targeting POSIX, it already has a function that does what you need: `getline`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *fh = ...;
char *line = NULL;
size_t buf_size = 0;

while (1) { 
   ssize_t line_len = getline(&line, &buf_size, fh);
   if (line_len == -1)
      break;

   // ...
}

free(line);
```

If not, `getline` can be implemented using using `fgets` and `realloc` in a loop. Just start with a arbitrarily-sized buffer.

Comment: I need to use fgets tho and the function must still be present